# Angularjs Validation without any form tag

Tags: angularjs, validation

I want to apply empty values validation on my page, but the question is if there are any other ways rather than using form tag or using ng-form directive?

Comment: Using form is most popular and easy, is there any hard reason to avoid form tag? if not i think u should use form

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot without Form tag or ng-form directive(AngularJS) to achieve empty validation. Under Form section only we can able to get

```
$error
$required
```

predefined tags will be available.